LoggerContextListener order establishment no longer honored after upgrading to SLF4J v2/Logback
I am going to do my best to explain this but it is fairly complicated. I work on a project that wants people to be able to override logback.xml settings using a java profile and properties.
For example if I have the following in logback.xml
<logger name="unit.test.l1.l2.l3" level="ERROR"/>

And then have a properties file like
logger.unit.test.l1.l2.l3=DEBUG

This worked fine in SLF4J v1 using the Logback LoggerContextListenercode and extending the ContextAwareBase class but I am finally forced to upgrade to 2 and when I do the tests fail saying that it is Error. Essentially it looks like some change in the LoggerFactory.bind()code function changed the way the context is created. Now it seems the logback function ContextSelectorStaticBinder.getSingleton()code before in the 1.x version it seems to call it here so there I can cleaning see it getting called but now it uses initialize.
Does anyone know how this pattern changed? Can someone point me at the proper release docs or PRs/Examples? I am guessing I am missing some Logback config in SLF4J or maybe need to add another class.
Update
Looking deeper this might be change on the Logback side where it looks like a whole section of code has been removed with no replacement (and leaving code commented without a TODO or instructions just seems bad)...
// private final ContextSelectorStaticBinder contextSelectorBinder =
// ContextSelectorStaticBinder.getSingleton();
//    private static Object KEY = new Object();
//    private volatile boolean initialized = false;
...
//        if (!initialized) {
//            return defaultLoggerContext;
//        
//
//        if (contextSelectorBinder.getContextSelector() == null) {
//            throw new IllegalStateException("contextSelector cannot be null. See also " + NULL_CS_URL);
//        }
//        return contextSelectorBinder.getContextSelector().getLoggerContext();

Why is this commented out and are there any more docs around this?

It's hard to help you with your actual problem since you haven't posted any code - and I don't think finding a reason for the change in Logback really helps you.
Spring property files can be used to override logger levels, but you need to set the properties under logging.level.
Here's a (working) test to illustrate:
@SpringBootApplication
class LoggerApp {
}

@SpringBootTest(
        classes = LoggerApp.class,
        properties = {
                "logging.level.playground.LoggerTest=DEBUG"
        }
)
public class LoggerTest {

    @Test
    public void testThatLoggingLevelIsOverriddenFromProperties() {
        var logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerTest.class);

        Assertions.assertTrue(logger.isDebugEnabled());
    }
}

Run with the following logback.xml:
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml"/>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/console-appender.xml" />
    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
    </root>
    <logger name="playground.LoggerTest" level="ERROR"/>
</configuration>

